# Property File Outisde of .WAR file

Tags: java

I need to be able to read in a property file, that lives outside of my war. My problem is that a need a solution that will allow me to tell my war file where my property file is located. Can this be done through bashrc variables and windows env variables?

I need to do this because I need to be able to drop the property file in different locations that could be away from the war file.

I am struggling to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will very much depends what the property file is for. Some libraries will have have the possibility of setting it on the command-line and others will allow you to explicitly load them in code.

In case of the latter, System.getProperties() can prove helpful, since it allows you to read properties passed to the JVM using the '-D' flag. For example

```
java -jar -Dfilelocation="yourfilelocation" yourapp.jar
```

would populate the system property 'filelocation' with the string 'yourfilelocation'. This could then be used in your code to load the property file (or whatever you want to do with it).

Since you are running inside some sort of application server, there are different ways you can accomblish this. For jetty you can put them in start.ini (or simply pass them on the command-line when you start jetty)

where tomcat uses an enviroment variable called JAVA_OPTS, so

```
JAVA_OPTS='-Dfilelocation=yourfilelocation' start.sh
```

would set the system property when you start tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to provide specific location by passing java argument or setting up environment varialble and read it from app to determine the location

and as a fallback (default) app should be announcing to look at

```
${user.home}/appname/some.peroperties
```

Comment: does user.home perform the same in windows os?

Comment: yes its O.S. independent you can read it like `System.getProperty("user.home");`

Answer (score 0):

You could defines a list of possible directories ... and try to read each one ...

I have a solution that read a property file in the file system using a default directory structure.

Eg: c:\properties\code-suit\prd\application.properties

Where:
code-suit is a variable defined by application name;
prd is a environment that I will use

Good luck